# How can we change the font of tableview header?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, fonts, textcolor

I am using some background color for the tabelView and style is grouped. The text in the header for the sections is not clear so I need to modify the the text color so that the header text should be visible. 
I want to know can we change the header text's color and size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding to terente's answer:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
        UIView* headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, 44.0)];
        //headerView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

        // Add the label
        UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, -5.0, 300.0, 90.0)];
        headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        headerLabel.opaque = NO;
        headerLabel.text = @"Header";
        headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        headerLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        //this is what you asked
        headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];

        headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
        headerLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        headerLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        [headerView addSubview: headerLabel];

        [headerLabel release];  

        // Return the headerView
        return headerView;
    }
    else return nil;
}
```

You can use `[UIFont fontWithName:@"<name of your font>" size:24.0];` for other fonts

Comment: thanks xs2bush for your quick response, now I am able to change the header title color

Comment: change `headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];` to the color that you want.

Comment: Don't forget to implement `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` or your section header won't be the right height to fit your new view.

Comment: Also don't forget to cache your views somewhere or they will be redrawn each time the section header appears which could be costly.

Answer (score 5):

Just implement

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

And return your custom view for header.

Edit:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIImageView *headerTitleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, kSectionHeaderHeight)];
    [headerTitleView setImage:sectionHeaderBackgroundImage];

    UILabel *sectionTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - 38) / 2, 5, 38, kSectionHeaderHeight - 10)];
    sectionTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    sectionTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    sectionTitleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    sectionTitleLabel.text = @"A";
    sectionTitleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"yourFont" size:13];
    [sectionTitleLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    [headerTitleView addSubview:sectionTitleLabel];

    return headerTitleView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) tableView : (UITableView*) tableView willDisplayHeaderView : (UIView*) view forSection : (NSInteger) section{

    [((UITableViewHeaderFooterView) *view).textLabel setFont:(UIFont...)];
}
```

and you can set the text label from the other table view delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
    [((UITableViewHeaderFooterView *) view).textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Your-Font-Name" size:((UITableViewHeaderFooterView *) view).textLabel.font.pointSize]];
}
```

Notes:

- This will set the font to a custom font but keep the `pointSize` the same.
- Also works for `willDisplayFooterView`.
- Don't forget to change `Your-Font-Name` to your font.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {

if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class]]) {
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerView = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView*)view;
    [headerView.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham Book" size:16.0f]];
}}
```

We can use **header.textlabel** object to change other "UILabel" properties for that label.